# windows developer program for IoT can program sketch to run on Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino, intel-galileo

I have visual studio installed in my machine. I installed windows developer program for IoT as well. I can create IoT project in Visual studio as well.
Now the question is, since Microsoft is working with Intel Galileo board, can i use an Arduino Uno board in this combination. I will write sketch in Visual Studio but install it on Arduino Uno for testing?

Is it possible? 
I am planning to purchase a developer kit soon and bit confused between which one i should purchase (Intel Galileo or Arduino)? Visual studio has as usual intellisense support which i think is not present in Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use for the Arduino Uno board the free [Visual Micro](http://www.visualmicro.com) PlugIn, which makes Microsoft Visual Studio 2008-2013 into full Arduino programming environment. There are detailed introductions on the [Arduino Playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/VisualMicro) site.

Answer (score -1):

I found this project on github: [Galileo-Sdk](https://github.com/ms-iot/galileo-sdk) I'ts work preaty good
This package is extension for Microsoft Visual studio, so you can programm and debug code there.
To add Package to VS you need to go Options > General > Package Source and add folder of Galileo-Sdk.